# Mathematica Exists/Resolve not giving "True" or "False"

Tags: parametric-functions

I have following function,

$f(\beta) = \left(1 - \frac{0.29}{A} + \frac{0.04 C}{A}\right) + \frac{1}{ 
 3.35 A + \frac{3.35 A^2C}{\left(6.5 - D\right) \left(A+B \right)} + \frac{ABC}{\left(6.5 - D\right) \left(A +B\right)} \beta } $

Where , $A, B, C >0$ and $100>\beta>0.01$

Also condition I have to maintain is $f(\beta)$ should be always positive.

Now problem I am trying to solve is to check if there exists any value of A, B and C  for $\beta < 1$ which will give me $f(\beta) > 1.8$.

So far I was able to do following,

```
f = (1 - (0.29/A) + (0.04*C/A) ) + 1/( 3.35*A  + (3.35*A^2*C)/((6.5 - D)*(A + B))  + (A*B*C*beta)/( (6.5 - D)*(A + B)));
Exists[{A, B, C }, {f > 1.8 &&  B > 0 && C > 0 && D > 0 && 0.01 < beta < 100}]
```

However, this was just giving me $\exists_{A,B,C}$ followed by exact same equation (Screenshot attached). I ever tried using *Resolve* and *Reduce* to see if it can give me "True" or "False" value. But that also gave me same exists equation. I am little confused with this result.

If it is telling me there exists such value, is there any way to get at least one of such parameter set to check if condition satisfy ?

[image]

Comment: C and D are protected symbols. I use lowercase for variables.

Comment: @bobbym : Thanks , didn't know this :)

Comment: You do not have to adhere to this but I think that the usual math convention is a,b,c... for constants and ...,w,x,y,z for variables,

Comment: Btw, this is NOT a simple mistake. Even without protected symbol , it was not giving me correct answer. Accepted answer is showing non trivial thing like using ForAll inside FindInstance (at least to new newcomers like me ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid confusion with symbols used by Mathematica, it is good practice to use undercase letters for your variables. Instead of Exists (you have too few variables) I would try Findinstance:

```
FindInstance[{f > 1.8 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && 0.01 < beta < 100}, {a, b, c, d, beta}]

(*  {{a -> -1., b -> 0.0959742, c -> 7.25037, d -> 3.25, beta -> 51.675}} *)
```

**Edit**

Above I looked at your problem with the exists quantor. Now I understand that that was not quite your problem. Always realize that before Mathematica can do something for you, you first have to give a very precise formulation of what you want Mathematica to do.  You ask:

== Check if there exists any value of a, b and c  for beta <1 which will give me f(beta)>1.8.

In this formulation you did not mention the variable `d`. Further, you consider `f`as a function of `beta` only, but it also depends on `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. Lastly, I think that  with 'for `beta` < 1' you mean  'for all `beta` with `beta` <1'.

I would formulate this problem in terms of relations between the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `beta`. That gives:

```
FindInstance[{ForAll[beta, 0.01<beta<1,
  (1-(0.29/a)+(0.04*c/a))+1/(3.35*a+(3.35*a^2*c)/((6.5-c)*(a+b))+
  (a*b*c*beta)/((6.5-d)*(a+b)))>1.8],
   a>0, b>0, c>0, d>0}, {a,b,c,d}]

(* $Aborted *)
```

Here, the problem for Mathematica is of course the verification of the forall condition. Moreover, there are 5 variables involved. That gives pretty complicated polynomial expressions, so I was not surprised that I had to abort this comuptation after 5 minutes.

But when we reduce the number of variables, it becomes less time consuming. We make a guess for `a` and `b` ourselves and then ask Mathematica to find an instance for `c` and `d`:

```
With[{a=0.9, b=1.2},
  FindInstance[{ForAll[beta, 0.01<beta<1,
   (1-(0.29/a)+(0.04*c/a))+1/(3.35*a+(3.35*a^2*c)/((6.5-c)*(a+b))+(a*b*c*beta)/((6.5-d)*(a+b)))>1.8],
   a>0, b>0, c>0, d>0}, {c, d}]
```

]

```
(* {{c->11.3292,d->2.93121}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also need to maintain condition that f(b) should be always positive. With FindIntance, I can find one parameter set but how will I put condition that f(b) is always positive ?

Comment: @Dexter. See my edit. I used a forall condition on `beta`. Of course, similarly you can use a forall conditions on `b`.